# How to group more andWhere, orWhere in Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
SELECT * FROM dg
WHERE 
     ( a < 1 AND b > 1)
  OR ( a > 1 AND ( 
                     (c = 3 AND B < 2) 
                  or (c = 4 AND B < 5 ))
     )
```

I don't sure how to properly group more `andWhere` and `orWhere`. I've found a example for group more AND but not example for OR.
For exp. `WHERE a=1 AND (a>1 Or b=2) AND (a>1 OR c=2)` working query is:

```
public function myQuery()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder( 'dg' )
                ->where("a = 1")
                ->andWhere("a > 1 OR b = 2")
                ->andWhere("a > 1 OR c = 3")
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

How can I use my SELECT in Doctrine2 to create `Query Builder`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For grouping and hierarchy of or/and and the like, you can link `and`'s and `or`'s using querybuilder's `->expr()` method chaining onto `->andX()` and `->orX()` respectively on your instance of QueryBuilder. You can check here for more information: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class

Basically you'll get something like the following to translate your second statement:

```php
// In this example I'll be assuming that 'dg' is an entity
// and that 'a', 'b' and 'c' are its attributes
// since, remember, Doctrine is designed specifically for using entities
// and make abstraction of the whole table model in your database

// First we'll create your QueryBuilder instance $qb
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('dg');

// Then we add our statements to the QueryBuilder instance
$qb
    ->where($qb->eq('dg.a', 1))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->gt('dg.a', 1),
        $qb->expr()->eq('dg.b', 2)
    ))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->gt('dg.a', 1),
        $qb->expr()->eq('dg.c', 3)
    ))
;

// Now you can use the QueryBuilder instance to, for instance, 
// have it do getResult (which in this case will return an array of 'dg' entities)
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

You can put orX()'s and andX()'s into other orX()'s and andX()'s as well, and you can add an arbitrary number of conditions in your andX() and orX(), to create very complex queryies.

Have fun :)

Comment: I edited the code to try and clarify. I had to assume quite a bit, because the code you provided doesn't exactly tell which entity you're trying to retrieve, but you should be able to get an example working through analogy. Do check out the link I provided for the Doctrine manual; it's very clear on how to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the tutorial that told me wise words on the subject:

> So even though there is an orWhere() function, don't use it - it can cause WTF moments.

The point in general being, even though the option is there, you are not forced to use them. In the case of complex where clauses it's hard to get right, controlling where the parentheses go, readability and such.

When I'm at this point I just put down an andWhere with the correct parentheses etc like with your example:

```
->addWhere("
    (a < 1 AND b > 1)
    OR (
        (a > 1) AND (
            (c = 3 AND B < 2) OR
            (c = 4 AND B < 5)
        )
    )
");
```

Though this might not be the 'correct way' (see the answer from @TomDeRoo) but at least I can read whats going on. Just know you don't always have to use everything a tool provides.

You are of course free to pick whatever solution you fancy.